# How diachronically stable is release type?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, sound-change, diachronic, glottal-stop

Are there examples of languages completely shifting from (vocalic) release of all coda stops to, say, nasal release?

I imagine substrate effects could account for some of these cases (cf. unreleased stops in Indo-Aryan Chakma, possible Tibeto-Burman influence?), but am wondering if any language has undergone an independent shift towards a new release type.

The English glottalization to a great extent could be seen as independent, but are there examples of a coda-releasing language shifting to, for example, a Mon-Khmer-type unreleased system? I'm particularly interested in the shift to nasal release. I have possible examples from Munda (where all coda stops are underlyingly voiced, nasally released in languages like Mundari and Ho) and some sociolects of Sinhala.

Comment: Precluding contact is a really tall order. Esp. in American English, suppression of release seems to be an ongoing real thing, and it's a stretch to attribute it to a long-latent Celtic substratum. Aren't you looking for the precursors of debuccalization?

Comment: @user6726 sorry, the substrate comment was in reference to Chakma, not English (I was talking about how English could fit the description of a shift in release type). And, yes, this shift could be an early step towards debuccalization (and devoicing) of all coda stops, but is it necessary that unreleased stops be accompanied by glottalization?

Comment: I would say yes (glottalization): that is *how* one gets unreleased stops. Of course that's an empirical question so I don't mean that as a definitional stipulation.

Comment: @user6726 Thanks. I ask because it has been argued that Hanoi Vietnamese, unlike neighboring Sino-Tibetan lects, does not glottalize its unreleased stops: Michaud (2004) supports this with acoustic evidence.

Comment: @user6726 What would motivate a language to nasally release all (voiced?) codas? Do you know of any diachronic pathways towards this?

Comment: It is AFAIK unique in the world's languages. If you take preglottalization to be the earlier state, I suppose this is one way to relieve pressure buildup without a particularly audible release.

Comment: There is no such thing as an unreleased stop. Unreleased stops result in death. No exceptions!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore, of course, I use "unreleased" in reference to no _audible_ release :)